# PyQGIS line_locate_point

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, iteration

Using the field calculator I'm able to get this working fine:

```
line_locate_point( geometry:=geometry(get_feature('trail', 'fid', '206')), point:=$geometry)
```

But what I would like to do is using Python to iterate through trails, selecting a set of points based on a common ID, and run this function. I'm not able to find if this is possible and if so, any examples.

Comment: What does that expression do?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do the whole thing in Python, rather than trying to pipe in a field calculator expression? Just explain what you want to do in each iteration